# Spawn players in different positions Unity Photon

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

I'm trying to spawn players in different positions. I use RPC for this, the players will spawn in different positions, as I want, BUT this method additionally duplicates (to be more precise, it will spawn copies of the player depending on the total number of all players) of the player, how can this be fixed? Maybe there is some kind of test for this? Or a better way?
If you add break after i++, then only the Master player and his copies will be saved.

```
public class PlayerManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    private PhotonView _photonView;
 
    private void Start()
    {
        _photonView = GetComponent<PhotonView>();
 
        if (_photonView.IsMine)
        {
            int i = 0;
            foreach (var p in PhotonNetwork.PlayerList)
            {
                _photonView.RPC(nameof(CreateController), p, i);
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
 
    [PunRPC]
    private void CreateController(int i)
    {
        var playerAvatar = PhotonNetwork.Instantiate(Path.Combine("PhotonPrefabs", "Player"), GameManager.instance.spawnPoints[i].position, Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like each player is spawning all the other players.  Network.Instantiate will create a copy on each connected client. Have each player spawn only themselves, or have one player (or server) spawn everybody.  You can change `if (_photonView.IsMine)` to `if (_photonView.IsHost)`, that may be sufficient, and replace the RPC with just the Instantiate code.

Comment: @hijinxbassist, In photon PUN 2 there is no IsHost, an analogue of IsMasterClient, but with this condition only the master player will be created. The essence of my task is to create players, but in specific positions so that they are not occupied.

Comment: I meant MasterClient, my mistake.  You are looping through all the connected players though, so that client is instantiating something for each player.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `CreateController` RPC is called by each client, leading to n^2 player instances being created. Use `photonView.IsMasterClient` in the `Start` method, instead of `photonView.IsMine`

For an even better solution that doesn't require the host to call RPCs, you can use `Array.IndexOf(PhotonNetwork.PlayerList, PhotonNetwork.LocalPlayer)` to get that same `i` number. That way you can just put the instantiate in the `Start` method;

```cs
//Change to extending MonoBehaviourPun and you get a "photonView" variable for free
public class PlayerManager : MonoBehaviourPun
{
    //private PhotonView _photonView;
 
    private void Start()
    {
        int i = Array.IndexOf(PhotonNetwork.PlayerList, PhotonNetwork.LocalPlayer);
        var playerAvatar = PhotonNetwork.Instantiate(Path.Combine("PhotonPrefabs", "Player"), GameManager.instance.spawnPoints[i].position, Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

Comment: your decision is almost correct, all these actions need to be stuffed into the _photonView.isMine condition, otherwise it will create n^2 players. Please edit your answer so that other developers don't get confused.

Comment: @КалашниковЯн That's only true if you make a PlayerManager for every single player in the game, which is... dumb? I'm assuming that the PlayerManager is a singleton, the same way the GameManager would be.